# geth never stop syncing on rinkeby testnet

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

when the currentBlock becomes close to the highestBlock, it stop growing, and the highestBlock begin to grow. A while later, the currentBlock begin growing again.

I run geth with command `geth --rinkeby --fast`.

the highestBlock on my geth is very close to the actual number on https://www.rinkeby.io/#faucet.

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 2401750,
  highestBlock: 2401826,
  knownStates: 14219701,
  pulledStates: 14205841,
  startingBlock: 2401554
}
> eth.blockNumber
0
```

logs below, seems normal:

```
INFO [06-04|15:34:52] Imported new state entries               count=621  elapsed=4.093ms   processed=14288823 pending=12362 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:34:56] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=713.868µs number=2401841 hash=db818c…70c969 ignored=0
INFO [06-04|15:34:57] Imported new state entries               count=1388 elapsed=9.091ms   processed=14290211 pending=12354 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:00] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=9.649ms   processed=14290979 pending=11944 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:02] Imported new state entries               count=607  elapsed=4.707ms   processed=14291586 pending=11757 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:05] Imported new state entries               count=768  elapsed=5.867ms   processed=14292354 pending=11629 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:07] Imported new state entries               count=601  elapsed=4.242ms   processed=14292955 pending=11759 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:09] Imported new state entries               count=601  elapsed=4.924ms   processed=14293556 pending=11479 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:09] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=711.566µs number=2401842 hash=39a2d8…5318ec ignored=0
INFO [06-04|15:35:10] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=3.093ms   processed=14293940 pending=11375 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:11] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=2.660ms   processed=14294324 pending=11365 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:13] Imported new state entries               count=601  elapsed=5.337ms   processed=14294925 pending=11094 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:17] Imported new state entries               count=985  elapsed=6.948ms   processed=14295910 pending=11024 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:20] Imported new state entries               count=602  elapsed=4.317ms   processed=14296512 pending=10940 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:25] Imported new state entries               count=602  elapsed=4.380ms   processed=14297114 pending=10973 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:25] Imported new block headers               count=1    elapsed=469.834µs number=2401843 hash=e8d3a7…152487 ignored=0
INFO [06-04|15:35:25] Imported new state entries               count=384  elapsed=2.758ms   processed=14297498 pending=11062 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:28] Imported new state entries               count=592  elapsed=5.524ms   processed=14298090 pending=11015 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:31] Imported new state entries               count=1210 elapsed=203.329ms processed=14299300 pending=10477 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
INFO [06-04|15:35:37] Imported new state entries               count=1033 elapsed=1.656ms   processed=14300333 pending=10590 retry=0   duplicate=6543 unexpected=9538
```

I think I've waited long enough, but the currentBlock just can't reach the highestBlock, even they are very close.

Is this common?

---

syncing finished. Theses numbers do not mean everything, just wait.

Comment: can i ask how much time consumed?

Answer (score 0):

There could still be a lot of states to process, even after the block synchronization was completed (i.e. when `currentBlock` almost reached `highestBlock`).

There is no clear way to know the total number of states:
`pulledStates` is the number of state trie entries already downloaded, and 
`knownStates` is the total number of state trie entries known about.

Synchronization is considered complete when a node has downloaded (pulled) all the states (known and unknown), until then it returns `0` to `eth.blockNumber` and `eth.getBalance`.

Answer (score 0):

Geth needs to sync state and blocks.
There are around 81M state entries atm.
The folder size is 28GB after full sync.

Answer (score 0):

*You will have to be patient to sync a node.*

It took me 60 hours to sync Rinkeby in fast mode. There were **125M state entries** and the folder size was **38GB** after synchronization. With time, both these numbers will grow.

You can type `eth.syncing` in Geth console. If you get 'False' as output, it means that syncing is finished. Otherwise you'll get various details about the blocks and the states.

By typing `eth.blockNumber` you will get the current block number. If the output is 0 then the syncing is not yet complete.

Here is the image when syncing was complete(all the states were pulled) and I started downloading the chain segments.
[Synchronized Rinkeby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz0E6.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a tiny python script to overview the process. It's here https://github.com/hayorov/ethereum-sync-mertics

My output:

```
2019-05-06 01:00:32 avg: 1827 max: 1938 min: 1378 states/s  remain: 136604075 states     4 peers    eta@ 20:46:28.165828
2019-05-06 01:00:37 avg: 1864 max: 1938 min: 1378 states/s  remain: 136595500 states     3 peers    eta@ 20:21:14.951050
2019-05-06 01:00:42 avg: 1791 max: 1938 min: 1378 states/s  remain: 136583359 states     3 peers    eta@ 21:11:16.481006
2019-05-06 01:00:48 avg: 1742 max: 1938 min: 1378 states/s  remain: 136580287 states     3 peers    eta@ 21:46:35.797305
2019-05-06 01:00:53 avg: 1721 max: 1938 min: 1378 states/s  remain: 136575694 states     3 peers    eta@ 22:03:01.154434
2019-05-06 01:00:58 avg: 1682 max: 1938 min: 1378 states/s  remain: 136569043 states     4 peers    eta@ 22:33:15.402442
2019-05-06 01:01:03 avg: 1698 max: 1938 min: 1378 states/s  remain: 136564293 states     3 peers    eta@ 22:20:27.458747
```